# Why is a long string of ?char?char etc.. in a regex so slow

Tags: regex

I'm trying to create a regex to conform to the following (iupac biology) rule:

```
<    Any characters before a < are considered optional and will be matched after the subsequence text has been found
```

In words that means:

Given CAT<ATTT, I want to find any text that matches ATTT exactly, and then if there is a T directly before that match, I want to include it in the match, if there is an A directly before the T, I want to include it as well. If there is also a C directly before the A I want to include it as well.

Here's an example of what that rule would look like when applied:

[image: iupac biology caret rule]

More examples:

```
CAT<ATTT (example pattern)
CATA ATTT (left side unmatched, right side matched)
CG ATATTT (left side unmatched, right side matched)
```

```
GGGT<GAGGGGGG  (example pattern)
T GGTGAGGGGGG  (left side unmatched, right side matched)
GGG GAGGGGGG   (left side unmatched, right side matched)
```

To satisfy this rule. I basically add a question mark to all the characters that come before the "<". For example,

```
TTGATAGCCATCATCATATCGAAGTTTCACTACCCTTTTTCCATTTGCCATCTATTGAAGTAATAATAGGC<GCATG
```

becomes:

```
T?T?G?A?T?A?G?C?C?A?T?C?A?T?C?A?T?A?T?C?G?A?A?G?T?T?T?C?A?C?T?A?C?C?C?T?T?T?T?T?C?C?A?T?T?T?G?C?C?A?T?C?T?A?T?T?G?A?A?G?T?A?A?T?A?A?T?A?G?G?C?GCATG
```

However I've found that adding a bunch of optional ? characters creates a very slow regex (at least when run in the chrome browser). You can try for yourself by running the following code in your browser:

```
"GACGTCTTATGACAACTTGACGGCTACGCATGATCATTCACTT".match("C?A?T?A?T?CT?T?G?A?T?A?G?C?C?A?T?C?A?T?C?A?T?A?T?C?G?A?A?G?T?T?T?C?A?C?T?A?C?C?C?T?T?T?T?T?C?C?A?T?T?T?G?C?C?A?T?C?T?A?T?T?G?A?A?G?T?A?A?T?A?A?T?A?G?G?C?GCATG", "gi")
```

Or if that is fast for you, run this one:

```
"GACGTCTTATGACAACTTGACGGCTACGCATGATCATTCACTT".match("T?T?G?A?T?A?G?C?C?A?T?C?A?T?C?A?T?A?T?CT?T?G?A?T?A?G?C?C?A?T?C?A?T?C?A?T?A?T?CT?T?G?A?T?A?G?C?C?A?T?C?A?T?C?A?T?A?T?C?G?A?A?G?T?T?T?C?A?C?T?A?C?C?C?T?T?T?T?T?C?C?A?T?T?T?G?C?C?A?T?C?T?A?T?T?G?A?A?G?T?A?A?T?A?A?T?A?G?G?C?GCATG", "gi")
```

My question is two fold. First, why is this regex so slow?  And second, how can I implement the rules pictured above (specifically the "<" and ">" ones) in a performant way using regex? (Or maybe it isn't possible?)

Please ask any clarifying questions if you have them.

Thanks so much!

Comment: It is slow due to backtracking.

Comment: I'm just now realizing that adding a ? after each previous character doesn't actually create a regex that matches the rule I described correctly

Comment: So, what are the pattern requirements?

Comment: Any bases before a < are considered optional, and are matched after the subsequent sequence has been found. There can only be 1 < in a sequence

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I've added additional examples above

Comment: It is far from clear. Given a `CAT<ATTT` string, you want to remove `CAT<` and search for `ATTT`, right? Please explain your problem in terms of text, I have no idea what base is and so on.

Comment: Given CAT<ATTT, I want to find any text that matches ATTT exactly, and then if there is a T directly before that match, I want to include it in the match, if there is an A directly before the T,  I want to include it as well. If there is also a C directly before the A I want to include it as well. Does that help?

Comment: Ok, so you need `(?:(?:(?:C)?A)?T)?ATTT`, see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/pBCiWI/1). However, it is always be slow since the optional patterns at the start of string add complexity (more backtracking steps).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew would (CAT|AT|T)?ATTTT not do it more efficiently

Comment: It is interesting, yes, the alternation works better here. But it is only because the alternatives start each with a different char.

Comment: I still do not see  a way to answer this question. Probably, *if you are using Python*, the simplest will be to use PyPi regex and use the `regex.REVERSE` flag to parse the string from right to left. It is also possible wiht .NET.

Answer (score 0):

A regex that looks like:

```
(CAT|AT|T)?ATTTT
```

works well for me. It is orders more performant than the previous (broken) solution I was attempting to use.

Note: I found that looking using reg.exec was including intermediary results that I didn't want. Thus the code I'm using looks like:

```
[..."CGCATATTT".matchAll("(CCAT|CAT|AT|T)?ATTT", "gi")]
```

Thanks to @WiktorStribiżew and my coworker for helping me find a good solution!